# Combining array of string pointers into one array

Tags: c

My Code works properly it's just a matter of implementing another segment. Is it possible to take all string pointers in token and concatenate them into one index of another array? For example have another array or array of pointers called *array1[32] that stores all the "concatenations" of token into one of the indexes of array1 if that makes any sense.

```
 printf("Enter text:\n");
 while((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
     str[i++] = ch;

 str[i] = '\0';
 i = 0;

 int spaces = 0;
 for(int counter = 0; counter < strlen(str) + 1; counter++){
     if(str[counter] == ' '){
         spaces++;
     }
 }

 cmd = strtok(str, " ");
 while(n <= spaces + 1 && (act_token = strtok(NULL, " "))){
     token[n] = act_token;
     n++;
 }
 token[n] = NULL;
 n = 1;
```

Comment: `strcat` `strcat`

Comment: @P__J__ can I do that with a array of string pointers though?

Comment: It is very unclear what you want to achieve. Are you looking for an array of character arrays or just a copy of the array of string pointers?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to copy all of the tokens into a new string without the spaces.  If that's what you want, you could do something like this.  First declare your array1 like this:

```
char *array1;
```

Then allocate memory for it after your initial loop before you reset `i`:

```
array1 = malloc(i + 1);
```

Then after tokenizing, you can copy the strings:

```
            strcpy(array1, cmd);
            for (i = 0; i < spaces; i++) {
                    strcat(array1, token[i]);
            }
            printf("concat: %s\n", array1);
```

One thing to take care of is to verify that your tokenization handles the scenario where there are no spaces.

Comment: You're right. I would like to have the spaces as well if possible and I would like to have multiple strings inside of array1; each index would have a different string that I could access like array1[1].... array1[n].

Comment: In that case, I don't know what you would put into each element of array1.  Perhaps you should update your question with sample input, like: `hello my name is tanq` and show what you want in the elements of `array1`.